# How do I parse the contents of hundreds of csvs that are in a list of dataframes and split on ";" and ";" in loops?

Tags: r, list, loops, count

I'm working with a large number (1,983) of CSV files. Posts on stackoverflow have said that lists are easier to work with so I've approached my task that way. I have read the CSVs in and gotten the first part of my task accomplished: what is the maximum number of concurrent users of the application? (A:203) Here's that code:

```
# get a list of the files
        files <- list.files("my_path_here",pattern="*.CSV$", recursive = TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
#read in the csv's and store them as a list of dataframes
 tables <- lapply(files, read.csv)
 #store the counts of the number of users here
 counts<-rep(NA,length(tables))
 #loop thru the files to find the count and store that value
     for (i in 1:length(files)) {          
           counts[i] <- length(tables[[i]][[2]])      
                 }
#what's the largest number?
max(counts)
#203
```

The 2nd part of the task is to show the count of each title for each file. The contents of each file will be something like this:

```
         compute_0001                   compute_0002
[1] 3/26/2015 6:00:00       Business System Manager;Lead CoPath Analyst                      
[2]                 Regional Histotechnologist;Hist Tech - Ht                        
[3]                 Regional Histotechnologist;Tissue Tech                           
[4]                 SDX Histotechnologist;Histology Tech                             
[5]                 SDX Histotechnologist;Histology Tech                             
[6]                 Regional Histotechnologist;Lab Asst II Histology                 
[7]                 CytoPrep Tech;Histo Tech - Ht                                    
[8]                 Regional Histotechnologist;Tissue Tech                           
[9]                 Histology Supervisor;Supv Reg Lab Unit                           
[10]                Histotech/FC Tech/PA/Diener;Pathology Tissue Technician;;CONTRACT
```

What will differ from file to file is the time stamp in compute_0001, name of the file and the number of users (ie length of the file).
My approach was to try this:

```
>col2 <- sapply(tables,summary, maxsum=300) # gives me a list of 1983 elements that is 23.6Mb
```

(I noticed that when doing a summary() on the files I would get something like this - which is why I was trying it)

```
>col2[[1]]
    compute_0001                                compute_0002
1] Business System Manager;Lead CoPath Analyst                  :1       
 [2] Regional Histotechnologist;Hist Tech - Ht                  :1         
 [3] Regional Histotechnologist;Tissue Tech                     :1         
 [4] SDX Histotechnologist;Histology Tech                       :1         
 [5] SDX Histotechnologist;Histology Tech                       :1         
 [6] Regional Histotechnologist;Lab Asst II Histology           :2         
 [7] CytoPrep Tech;Histo Tech - Ht                              :4         
 [8] Regional Histotechnologist;Tissue Tech             :1                        
 [9 Histotech/FC Tech/PA/Diener;Pathology Tissue Technician;;CONTRACT :1
```

The above is actually many different people. For my purposes, [2],[3], [6] and [8] are the same title (even though the stuff after the ";" is different. The truth is that even [4] and [5] could also be considered the same as [2,3,6,8]).

That ":1" (or generally ":#") is the number of users with that title at that particular time. I was hoping to grab that character, make it numeric and add them up to get a count of the users with each title for each file. Each file is an observation at a particular datetime.

I tried something like this:

```
>for (s in 1:length(col2)) {
>split <- strsplit(col2[[s]][,2], ":")
>#... make it numeric so I can do addition with it
>num <- as.numeric(split[[s]][2])
>#... and put it in the correct df
>tables[[s]]$count <- num

# After dealing with the ":" I was going to handle splitting on the first ";" 
>}
```

But I couldn't get the loop to iterate more than a single time or past the first element of col2.

A more experienced useR suggested something like this:

```
>strsplit(x = as.character(compute2[[s]]),split=";",fixed=TRUE)
```

He said "However this results in a messy list also, since there are multiple ";" in some lines. What I would #suggest is to use grep() with a regex that returns the text before the first ";"- use that with sapply(compute2,grep()) and then you can run sapply(??,table) on the list that is returned to tally the job titles."

I'd prefer not to get into regex but, following his advice, I tried:

```
>for (s in 1:length(tables)){
>+ split <- strsplit(x = >as.character(compute2[[s]]),split=";",fixed=TRUE)
>+ }
```

split is a list of only 122 , not nearly long enough so it's not iterating thru the loop either. So, I figured I'd skip the loop and try:

```
>title_split<- sapply(compute2, strsplit, x = as.character(compute2[[1]]),split=";",fixed=TRUE)
```

But that gave me more than 50 warnings and a matrix that had 105,000+ elements that was 20.2Mb in size.

Like I said, I'd prefer to not venture into the world of regex, since I think I should be able to split on the ":" first and then the first of the ";" and return the string that precedes the ";". I'm just not sure why the loop is failing.

What I eventually want is a table that shows the count of each title (collapsed for duplicates like [2],[3], [6] and [8] above) for each file (which represents an observation at a particular datetime). I'm pretty agnostic as to approach, so if I have to do it via regex, then so be it.

Sorry for the lengthy post but I suspect that part of my problem (besides being brand new to stackoverflow, R and not understanding regex well) is that I'm not well versed in list manipulation and I wanted you to have the context.

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: For your first task, you can count the number of rows in each data frame as follows: `counts = sapply(tables, nrow)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data isn't easily reproducible, so I've created a simple list of fake data that I hope captures the essence of your data.

Make a list of fake data frames:

```
string1  = "53 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text" 
string2  = "54 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text" 
string3  = "CytoPrep Tech;text2 - more text"

tables = list(df1=data.frame(compute=c(string1, string2, string3)), 
              df2=data.frame(compute=c(string1, string2, string3)))
```

Count the number of rows in each data frame:

```
counts = sapply(tables, nrow)
```

Add a column that extracts job titles from the compute column. The regex pattern skips zero or more digit characters (`[0-9]*`) followed by zero or one space character (`?`) and then captures everything up to, but not including, the first semi-colon(`([^;]*);`) and then skips every character after the semi-colon (`.*`).

```
tables = sapply(names(tables), function(df) {
  cbind(tables[[df]], title=gsub("[0-9]* ?([^;]*);.*", "\\1", tables[[df]][,"compute"]))
}, simplify=FALSE)


tables

$df1
                                          compute                      title
1 53 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text Regional histotechnologist
2 54 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text Regional histotechnologist
3                 CytoPrep Tech;text2 - more text              CytoPrep Tech

$df2
                                          compute                      title
1 53 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text Regional histotechnologist
2 54 Regional histotechnologist;text2 - more text Regional histotechnologist
3                 CytoPrep Tech;text2 - more text              CytoPrep Tech
```

Make a table of counts of each title for each data frame in tables:

```
title.table.list = lapply(tables, function(df) table(df$title))

title.table.list

$df1

CytoPrep Tech Regional histotechnologist 
            1                          2 

$df2

CytoPrep Tech Regional histotechnologist 
            1                          2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm trying to understand your code so in running it I got an error on your tables = sapply(names(df.list), function(df) {
+     cbind(df.list[[df]], title=gsub("([^;]*);.*", "\\1", df.list[[df]][,"compute"]))
+ }, simplify=FALSE) call: df.list not found. Was that supposed to be a placeholder and not an actual object? Also, I can see immediately that one thing you did in creating your "tables" object that I didn't do was to name the columns. I will go back and try doing that.

Comment: `df.list` was just my original name for the list. I forgot to change all of them to `tables` to match your name for the list. Sorry about that. I've fixed it now. Regarding your comment about naming the columns: Don't your data frames already have column names? If not, R would automatically give them generic names anyway.

Comment: Or do you mean that the list elements themselves (the data frames) don't have names? For example, where I've named the data frames in the list df1 and df2, yours don't have names? If you use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, you'll end up with a list where each element has the name of the csv file it came from: `sapply(files, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean where you named the data frames in the list as df1 and df2. Your sapply(files, read.csv, simplyfy=FALSE) worked like a charm. I got your code to work, but I'm wondering what the next step is for getting the count of each title for each data frame? If the truncated result of one of the elements from title.table.list is 52             SDX Histotechnologist
53        Regional Histotechnologist
54        Regional Histotechnologist
55       Histotech/FC Tech/PA/Diener
   how do I count up [53] and [54] as 2 instances of the same title within title.table.list?

Comment: I've updated my answer to deal with digits and spaces before the job title you want to capture. If there are other patterns in the data that you want to exclude or include, you'll need to add additional regex patterns to capture or exclude them. That doesn't have to be done in a single call to `gsub`, by the way. For example, in the example above, I could have run the original version of the `gsub` function and then run a second `gsub` to remove the digits and spaces.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a specific list of possible job titles, you can create a vector of those job titles and then search for them within the values of compute. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130129/find-matches-of-a-vector-of-strings-in-another-vector-of-strings) for an example of how to do this. Note that in this case you'll of course miss job titles that aren't in your vector of job titles or that are misspelled or that have any other inconsistencies (e.g., unusual formatting or characters).

Comment: I'm sorry I may have mislead you. What I was trying to say is that the elements of title.table.list had an index of [52] for SDX Histotechnologist, [53] Regional Histotechnologist, [54] Regional Histtechnologist, etc. not that they had those characters as part of their title. I'm not looking to search, I'm looking to count, where [53] is the same as [54] so I should count that as 2. But I obviously need to do that for everything in title.table.list (or tables). Thanks for hanging in there with me as I work thru this.

Comment: If the index isn't part of the character string, then how would the index affect the count of each value?