# How do I extract appearances of a vector of strings in another vector of strings using R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

I have a vector of strings like this :

```
strings <- tibble(string = c("apple, orange, plum, tomato",
                             "plum, beat, pear, cactus",
                             "centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit"))
```

And I have a vector of fruit:

```
fruits <- tibble(fruit =c("apple", "orange", "plum", "pear"))
```

What I'd like is a data.frame/tibble with the original `strings` data.frame with a second list or character column of all the fruit contained in that original column.  Something like this.

```
strings <- tibble(string = c("apple, orange, plum, tomato",
                             "plum, beat, pear, cactus",
                             "centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit"),
                   match = c("apple, orange, plum",
                             "plum, pear",
                             "pear")
                  )
```

I've tried `str_extract(strings, fruits)` and I get a list where everything is blank along with the warning:

```
Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)):
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I've tried `str_extract_all(strings, paste0(fruits, collapse = "|"))` and I get and I get the same warning message.

I've looked at this [Find matches of a vector of strings in another vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130129/find-matches-of-a-vector-of-strings-in-another-vector-of-strings), but that doesn't seem to help here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option. First we split each row of the `string` column into separate strings (right now `"apple, orange, plum, tomato"` is all one string). Then we compare the list of strings to the contents of the `fruits$fruit` column and store a list of the matching values in the new `fruits` column.

```r
library("tidyverse")
strings <- tibble(
  string = c(
    "apple, orange, plum, tomato",
    "plum, beat, pear, cactus",
    "centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit"
  )
)

fruits <- tibble(fruit =c("apple", "orange", "plum", "pear"))

strings %>%
  mutate(str2 = str_split(string, ", ")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fruits = list(intersect(str2, fruits$fruit)))
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   string                            str2      fruits   
#>   <chr>                             <list>    <list>   
#> 1 apple, orange, plum, tomato       <chr [4]> <chr [3]>
#> 2 plum, beat, pear, cactus          <chr [4]> <chr [2]>
#> 3 centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit <chr [4]> <chr [1]>
```

Created on 2018-08-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks--I tried looking at the documentation for `rowwise()` and I was fairly confused.  Any advice regarding this function?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using purrr

```
strings <- tibble(string = c("apple, orange, plum, tomato",
                         "plum, beat, pear, cactus",
                         "centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit"))

fruits <- tibble(fruit =c("apple", "orange", "plum", "pear"))

extract_if_exists <- function(string_to_parse, pattern){
  extraction <- stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(string_to_parse, pattern)
  extraction <- unlist(extraction[!(is.na(extraction))])
  return(extraction)
}

strings %>%
  mutate(matches = map(string, extract_if_exists, fruits$fruit)) %>%
  mutate(matches = map(string, str_c, collapse=", ")) %>%
  unnest
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base-R solution:

```
strings[["match"]] <- 
  sapply(
    strsplit(strings[["string"]], ", "), 
    function(x) {
      paste(x[x %in% fruits[["fruit"]]], collapse = ", ")
    }
  )
```

Resulting in:

```
  string                            match              
  <chr>                             <chr>              
1 apple, orange, plum, tomato       apple, orange, plum
2 plum, beat, pear, cactus          plum, pear         
3 centipede, toothpick, pear, fruit pear
```