# R - Find if characters of a vector are in another vector

Tags: r

I have a doubt very similar to this topic here: [Find matches of a vector of strings in another vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130129/find-matches-of-a-vector-of-strings-in-another-vector-of-strings?rq=1).

I have a vector of clients, and if the name indicates that is a commercial client, I need to change the type in my data.frame.

So, suppose that:

```
commercial_names <- c("BAKERY","MARKET", "SCHOOL", "CINEMA")
clients <- c("JOHN XX","REESE YY","BAKERY ZZ","SAMANTHA WW")
```

I tried the code in the topic cited before, but I had an error:

```
> grepl(paste(commercial_names, collape="|"),clients)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
Warning message:
In grepl(paste(commercial_names, collape = "|"), clients) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What am I doing wrong? I would thank any help.

Comment: What exact output are you trying to get?

Comment: I want verify which one in `clients` has a commercial name. So I want to get:
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct but for a typo:

```
grepl(paste0(commercial_names, collapse = "|"), clients) # typo: collape
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Given the typo, the `commercial_names` are not collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this with a one-liner but a loop seems to do the trick.

```
sapply(clients, function(client) {
  any(str_detect(client, commercial_names))
})
> JOHN XX    REESE YY   BAKERY ZZ SAMANTHA WW 
> FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was trying to do this with `apply`, but I don't know how to use this family of functions (`apply`, `lapply`, `sapply`, `mapply`) properly.

Comment: Learning `lapply` and `sapply` will make your life a lot easier. `lapply` does the same this as `apply` by loops over vectors instead of rows/columns. `sapply` is like `lapply` but will also try to simplify the output.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way of to do this, with the command `%like%` of package `data.table`:

```
> clients %like% paste(commercial_names,collapse = "|")
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too:

```
clients.first <- gsub(" ..", "", clients)
clients.first %in% commercial_names
```

This returns:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You might need to change the regular expression for `gsub` if your clients data is more heterogeneous though.